# How to define a function which repeats itself when passed an argument

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there an easy way to define a function which repeats itself when passed an argument?

For example, I've defined the following function

```
(defun swap-sign ()
  (interactive)
  (search-forward-regexp "[+-]")
  (if (equal (match-string 0) "-")
      (replace-match "+")
    (replace-match "-"))
  )
```

I'd like `C-u swap-sign` to call `swap-sign` four times.

I've tried

```
(defun swap-sign (&optional num)
  (interactive)
  (let ((counter 0)
 (num (if num (string-to-number num) 0)))
    (while (<= counter num)
      (search-forward-regexp "[+-]")
      (if (equal (match-string 0) "-")
   (replace-match "+")
 (replace-match "-"))           
      (setq counter (1+ counter)))))
```

but `C-u swap-sign` still only runs swap-sign (or perhaps more precisely, the body of the while-loop) once. I'm guessing it is because `if num` is not the right way to test if `num` is an empty string.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better/easier way to extend `swap-sign`?

Comment: Is this just to change the sign. Wouldn't you just determine if the num was odd and change it once ?

Comment: Each call to `swap-sign` advances the cursor point to the first character after the match. So calling it four times should swap four signs. I'm calling it on strings like `1231.196+760.489+213.553+122.165-24.633`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun swap-sign (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (dotimes (i arg)
    (search-forward-regexp "[+-]")
    (if (equal (match-string 0) "-")
        (replace-match "+")
      (replace-match "-"))))
```

See the documentation of the `interactive` special form for more details:
<kbd>C-h f</kbd>`interactive`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell emacs to expect, and pass the parameter in, by adding a "p" as the parameter specification for interactive (`M-x apropos interactive` to get the documentation). Here I've made the minimal change to your code to get it to work - note, however, that you don't need the let/while to do the iteration, and the arg doesn't need to be optional.

```
(defun swap-sign (&optional num)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((counter 1))
    (while (<= counter num)
      (search-forward-regexp "[+-]")
      (if (equal (match-string 0) "-")
      (replace-match "+")
    (replace-match "-"))           
      (setq counter (1+ counter)))))
```

Note that you don't need to convert the parameter from a string - using "p" tells emacs to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to fix the code with minimal changes.